How to create a 3D array of items based a matrix with Z-coordinates?
I'm new to Blender
I want to create an X-Y-Z matrix with identical glass spheres. This is the model for building a very nice lamp in my hallway. In the X-direction I have 27 available positions, in the Y-direction 11. Each position can only be used once. So the matrix of X-Y coordinates is fixed, the only variable is the Z-coordinate per X-Y position. This is the height where the glass sphere (the lamp bulb) is attached to the connection wire coming from the top.
I managed to define the glass sphere itself, and I know how the Array function works. This way, I can create the 27x11 array but only with one single Z-coordinate. So how can I project the 27x11 matrix with Z-coordinates onto my 2D X-Y mesh?
By the way I also added a light point into the bulb but I understand that this cannot be used for translations as it is not a mesh.
What is the solution for this? Drawing a sphere inside the glass bulb that is light emitting? I don't know how to do this.

Hello and welcome. Images illustrating what you have and what you are trying to achieve will go a long way for users trying to interpret how to help you

Thanks for the tip. I didn't see the option to add pictures...

Edit your question and the toolbar above the body text has an image icon on it. You can also drag and drop an image into the text edit field but you need to be careful to leave enough space above and below the image or it will appear in the middle of the text.

Are you talking about random height distribution on the Z axis or do you have specific height values for each of the lamps?

Thanks Gordon, I will prepare a picture. The Z-heights are defined, not random. The sphere diameter is 10 and the X and Y pitches are also 10. So I have a 27x11 matrix of spheres. When the Z-value is the same for all, they all tough each other. Now I want to define the Z-values but preferably not 1-by-1. I want to use a 27x11 matrix that contains the Z-values I have in mind. And I want to project those onto the 27x11 fixed X-Y matrix (with pitch 10 in both directions).
